# How would you model one-to-many and many-to-many in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

How would you model the following entities, and query them in Node.js?

```
User --> has many Posts
Post --> each Post belongs to a single User
Image --> each Image belongs to either a User or a Post or an Organization
Organization --> each Organization has many Users,
             --> each User can belong to many Organizations
```

Would you create each entity in a separate table and have a field pointing to an owner entity (a la FK)?
Would you store all of them in one big Organization table containing nested json fields, with denormalized data duplicated multiple times across different documents? if so - how would you go about updating a User field that belongs to several Organizations?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following method

```
User --> user detail,image and organization id have in user table 
Post --> each Post and image belongs to single user id 
Image --> each Image belongs to either a User or a Post or an Organization
Organization --> organization detail and image
```

Answer (score 0):

Relational data modeling is very different in NoSQL, compared to SQL (RDBMS), databases. There are a lot a great articles and videos on relational data modeling in DynamoDB. [This article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html) is a relatively simple example that you can use to help you get started.

As for the NodeJs part, it's just using the SDK to run the queries as outlined in the article. You'll primarily use the `getItem` and `query` functions.